# Vim in Powershell inserts unwanted UTF-8 characters when using the numpad

Tags: vim, powershell

When running `Vim` from `Powershell`, using the number pad in `insert` mode is sending the following characters:

```
1: ÎÞ
2: Îâ
3: Îæ
4: Îê
5: Îî
6: Îò
7: Îö
8: Îú
9: Îþ
10: ÎÚ
```

How can I allow the number pad buttons to instead insert their respective numeric digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `_vimrc` file:

```
:inoremap ÎÞ 1
:inoremap Îâ 2
:inoremap Îæ 3
:inoremap Îê 4
:inoremap Îî 5
:inoremap Îò 6
:inoremap Îö 7
:inoremap Îú 8
:inoremap Îþ 9
:inoremap ÎÚ 0
```

Comment: did you immediately answer your question?

Comment: Yes. This is [commonplace on Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).